# Posicionar tabelas com comandos no php

Tags: php, css, html5

Estou fazendo um programa que cria variáveis, e as mostra em duas tabelas com um `echo`. Junto nesse `echo`, eu coloquei uma table com um style dentro.Porém, na hora de testar o código, a formatação não se aplica.

```
echo
'<table style="postion:absolute; right:100px;" border="1">
<tr><td>Weapon</td><td>'.$weapon.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Armor</td><td>'.$armor.'</td></tr>
</table><br><br>    
';
echo
'<table style="postion:absolute; left:100px;""border="1">
<tr><td>Ouro</td><td>'.$money.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Health</td><td>'.$health.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mana</td><td>'.$mana.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Dextery</td><td>'.$dextery.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Defense</td><td>'.$defense.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Damage</td><td>'.$damage.'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Range</td><td>'.$distance.'</td></tr>
</table><br><br>    
';
```

Como faz tempo que não uso css, estou meio enferrujado, então não sei o que devo fazer para consertar esse problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que vc escreveu a propriedade CSS errado!

Ve escreveu `postion:absolute;`, a palavra `postion` está errada, faltou um `i` depois do `s`

O correto é `pos**i**tion`

```
position:absolute;
```

Além disso aqui vc deixou uma `"` sobrando, `style="postion:absolute; left:100px;""border="1"`. Vc tem que tirar essa Aspas `"` antes do `border="1"`

Seu código corrigido

```html
<table style="position:absolute; right:100px;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Weapon</td>
    <td>'.$weapon.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Armor</td>
    <td>'.$armor.'</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<table style="position:absolute; left:100px;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Ouro</td>
    <td>'.$money.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>'.$name.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Health</td>
    <td>'.$health.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mana</td>
    <td>'.$mana.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dextery</td>
    <td>'.$dextery.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Defense</td>
    <td>'.$defense.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Damage</td>
    <td>'.$damage.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Range</td>
    <td>'.$distance.'</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
```